# Why is Firefox not sending Referer in HTTP headers when I play HTML5 mp3 files?

Tags: html, firefox, browser, header, http-headers

I am having the problem that Firefox is not sending the Referer in the HTTP headers when I'm accessing an MP3 file through HTML5.

I'm using the player from jPlayer.org to play mp3 files, and I'm trying to prevent people from downloading the songs by reading the URL from a HTTP-sniffer/FireBug/similar. My approach to this is to check the HTTP headers in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^play/(\S+)$ /uploads/error.mp3
RewriteRule ^play/(\S+)$ /uploads/mp3/$1.mp3
```

These three lines tells the browser to play error.mp3 if the HTTP-referer is not set to something with mydomain.com. Otherwise, it gets the real mp3 file.

This works fine in Chrome, Internet Explorer 7/8/9, Safari(PC) and Opera. However, in Firefox (both PC and Mac) and Safari (Mac), it doesn't work. It seems this is because the HTTP referer is not sent at all. When I look in FireBug, I can't see the Referer any place in the Request-headers, so I guess it's not sent at all? I can see it in Chrome when I look in the Network tab in the web developer tools.

Is anyone else familiar with this problem? Do you have any idea how I can prevent download of the MP3 files or at least make it harder to download? Passing the MP3 files through PHP doesn't seem to work, as pause/resume won't work.

Comment: Which Firefox version is this?  Per https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=584480 Firefox 4 and later should be sending a referrer header.

Comment: It's Firefox version 11.

Comment: I redirected the play/ URL to a PHP file and e-mailed the $_SERVER array to myself to check it. I can confirm that Chrome sends the HTTP_REFERER and Firefox doesn't. I guess the bug is not completely fixed yet.

Comment: Can you please point to a testcase that shows the problem?  I don't see how there can possibly be a request without a referer here, unless something more is going on than what you say...

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Firefox supports the MP3 format within HTML5 audio. Maybe you should try this code with ogg files as well?

See [Media formats supported by the HTML audio and video elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Media_formats_supported_by_the_audio_and_video_elements).

Answer (score 0):

Like tim said, Firefox does not support MP3 in HTML5 http://caniuse.com/#search=audio in which case you should have a fallback to oog or wav.

Of course you said you are using the player from jplayer.org, which has flash fallbacks and in that case we are not really dealing with html5 anymore.

Supported html5 formats from jPlayer
http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#reference-html5-audio-format

**HTML5 Audio Format**

- Firefox (OSX, Win): WEBMA, OGA
- Safari (OSX, Win): MP3, M4A
- Mobile Safari iOS4 (iPad, iPhone, iPod): MP3, M4A
- Opera (OSX, Win): WEBMA, OGA
- Chrome (OSX, Win): WEBMA, OGA, MP3, M4A
- IE9 (Win): MP3, M4A (Can install the WebM codec.)

So most likely your header stuff is related to FF not supporting mp3 anyways.

It could also be something wierd like missing mime type on server. Then again if we are logical, any request a browser makes should be accompanied by a referrer url whether it's requesting a file it supports or not ..hmm.

One thing you could try is instead of linking the mp3 directly is give it an id, and make a request to your server for that, then via a redirect return an mp3.

And for sanity sake ..test it with an oog/wav, and also remove your referrer detection ..just to make sure it works at all :)

That said, if you are really concerned with leeches, i wouldn't put too much weight on referrer information, as that's pretty simple to spoof both in FF & Chrome. With a handcrafted http-client (just a few lines of code in most languages) you can spoof just about anything under the sun: cookies, referrer, cross-domain policies, and whatnot ..anyways getting off topic :)

But yes, referrer information will protect you from 95% of the population out there.